# Errors when trying to mock an async fetch function in Jest spec

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing tests for my app but running into problems when I try to mock an async fetch function. No matter what I try, I get:

```
asyncFetch.mockReturnValue is not a function
```

Which leads me to believe the function is not being mocked. However, I do not know where the problem lies.

This is the test:

```html
import emailSignin from 'api/emailSignin';

jest.mock('api/helpers/asyncFetch');

describe('API Auth', () => {
  describe('login', () => {
    it('has a happy path', async () => {
      const asyncFetch = require('api/helpers/asyncFetch').default;

      asyncFetch.mockReturnValue({
        json: () => 'it worked',
      });

      const response = await emailSignin('bob', 'password');
      expect(response).toEqual('it worked');
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the module I am trying to mock:

```html
import {
  ClientError,
  ServerError,
  ValidationError,
} from 'api/helpers/errors';

async function asyncFetch(url, requestConfig = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, requestConfig);
  const responseBody = await response.json();
  const { statusText, status } = response;

  switch (status) {
    case 400:
    case 401:
    case 403:
      throw new ClientError(statusText, status);
    case 422:
      throw new ValidationError(statusText, status, responseBody.errors);
    case 500:
    case 501:
    case 502:
    case 503:
    case 504:
    case 505:
      throw new ServerError(statusText, status);
    default:
      return response;
  }
}

export default asyncFetch;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To mock an module in jest you can do it like this in the initial `mock` call:

```
jest.mock('api/helpers/asyncFetch', ()=>({
  json: () => 'it worked'
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That is one of the things I already tried but without any result. I get another error back

`TypeError: (0 , _asyncFetch2.default) is not a function`  and when I try to console log, it says `undefined`.

Comment: could you please add the code of the module to your question.

Comment: I added it in the post

Comment: So why you call `require('api/helpers/asyncFetch').default` anyway, shouldn't it be just `require('api/helpers/asyncFetch')`. I always use `import`, where it would look like this: `import asyncFetch from 'api/helpers/asyncFetch' `

Comment: Then I get `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`. And when I console log, I get the whole function back, not a mock Constructor. It looks like the problem is deeper then just the require or import. I have the feeling jest is just doing nothing.

Comment: When I combine your first answer ( the explicit mock) and the import, the console.log returns the mocked value but the error is:

`TypeError: (0 , _asyncFetch2.default) is not a function`